# Trigger action in R shiny with a generic shiny widgets without specifying its complete inputID

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm creating server side some numericInput widgets using insertUI function, naming each of these object like "num_input_x" where x goes from 1 to whatever (the total number can increase or decrease depending on some conditions set by the user during the session).

Now I would like each of these dynamically created numericInput to trigger the same action.

The problem is that, in my knowledge, with observeEvent or observe you need to specify the exact inputID  name which is being observed and triggers that action.

To make it simple, I would need something like this that works:

`observeEvent(input[["num_input_*"]], {#action here})`

or this:

`observeEvent(lapply(listX,function(n) input[[paste0("num_input_",n)]]), {#action here})`

where * stands for whatever character(s) and listX the list containing all the numbers used to name the numericInput widgets.

Morevoer, it should be possible to trigger the action multiple times, not only once.

Many thanks for the help in advance

Comment: The second way does not work?

Comment: Actually yes. I thought it was not a real solution but just made up by me. Should be more confident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have each numeric input react separately, you can actually swap the order of `lappy` and `observeEvent`.

```r
library(shiny)

make_num_input <- function(id) {
  numericInput(paste0("num_inp_", id), "number", 0, 0, 10)
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  lapply(as.character(1:3), make_num_input)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  lapply(as.character(1:3), function(id) {
    name <- paste0("num_inp_", id)
    observeEvent(input[[name]], {
      msg <- sprintf("%s is now %d\n", id, input[[name]])
      cat(msg)  
    })    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

More modern approach to this type of implementation would be to use the shiny module framework ([Official page](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)).

```r
library(shiny)

make_num_input <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  numericInput(ns("num_inp"), "number", 0, 0, 10)
}

module <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$num_inp, {
      msg <- sprintf("%s is now %d\n", id, input$num_inp)
      cat(msg)  
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    lapply(as.character(1:3), make_num_input)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  lapply(as.character(1:3), module)  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```